# Return numberOfRowsInComponent & titleForRow in UIPickerview based on another UIpickerview's didSelectRow

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

Good day to all,

I tried explaining my query in the subject line.
As I understand and from what I see in the code, all pickerviews are initialized in ViewDidLoad(), which means that all have their data set.
As part of my data validation, which in this case is extremely important, I want to set the following pickerviews according to the previous ones selection.

Where I get stuck is to populate the following pickerview's titles with the 'new' data and reloading the view.

Ideally I would like the views to appear as previous selections are made.

If you know how to do this logically please let me know, I will appreciate any help I can get at the moment!

Comment: means u have 2 pickerview, changed picker 1 and picker 2 is set as previous of picker 1?

Comment: Let me explain the data. When registering the user sets a certain value, for example 8.

Comment: Let me explain the data. When registering the user sets a certain value, for example 8. Later on the user then enters another set of data based on the value 8 which have 4 sub sets. For the first subset the user enters for eg. 3, meaning the rest of the subsets must be total 5 and not 8 anymore. So the next pickerview will only have 5 rows instead of 8. And so on. I guess I can also have 4 components in the pickerview instead of more pickerviews. Question then will be how to add the other components as the previous ones are selected? Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean by logically, but you just use if statements and switches to determine what's been selected and what to present based on that selection. Then you reload the data.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView,
            didSelectRow row: Int,
             inComponent component: Int)
{
    if component == 0
    {
        switch row{
        case 0:
           self.titlesForComponentOne = ["One","Two","Three","Four"]
        case 1:
           self.titlesForComponentOne = ["One","Two"]
        default:
           self.titlesForComponentOne = ["One","Three","Four"]
         }
     }else if component == 1
     {
         switch row{
         case 0:
            self.titlesForComponentTwo = ["Three", "Four"]
         case 1:
         ….
     self.picker.reloadAllComponents() // or just ones that need to be updated
}

func pickerView( pickerView: UIPickerView,
numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    switch component{
    case 0:
       return self.titlesForComponentZero.count
    case 1:
       return self.titlesForComponentOne.count
    case 2:
       ….  
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking it will be in this way.